# What kind of distribution is $f_X(x) = 2 \lambda \pi x e^{-\lambda \pi x ^2}$?

Tags: distributions, confidence-interval, estimation, self-study

What kind of function is:

$f_X(x) = 2 \lambda \pi x e^{-\lambda \pi x ^2}$

Is this a common distribution? I am trying to find a confidence interval of $\lambda$ using the estimator $\hat{\lambda}=\frac{n}{\pi \sum^n_{i=1} X^2_i}$ and I am struggling to prove if this estimator has Asymptotic Normality.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe helps: if Y is distributed exponentially, then X=Y^2 is distributed with f_X. You can have a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) for the MLE of Y...

Comment: @teucer, sorry did not see your comment, so I posted practically the same answer.

Comment: always, always indicate that the question is related to homework. The homework is for you to learn, just getting the correct answer will not help you, and may even hurt you in the long run. I am surmising that this is a homework from the question of another user.

Comment: @mpiktas, this question was related to a small part of a homework problem, but I didn't phrase the question in a way someone could simply tell me the answer. It was my every intention to understand the concepts and then solve my homework myself.

Comment: your wording of the question was exemplary, this is how the homework questions should be asked. But knowing the problem context usually helps a lot in providing good answer.

Comment: @mpiktas But your answer says that if $Y$ is an exponential random variable with parameter $\pi\lambda$, then the **square root** of $Y$ has the distribution asked about by OP Mitch whereas teucer's answer says the **square** of $Y$  has the distribution asked about. So, how is your answer practically the same as teucer's (and which one should we believe)?

Comment: @DilipSarwate mine :). If $Y$ is exponential then $P(\sqrt{Y}<x)=P(Y<x^2)=F_\lambda(x^2)$, where $F_\lambda$ is the cdf of exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$. Practically the same means that you have either root or square. Not the best use of expression practically the same.

Comment: @mpiktas  Yes, I know your characterization is correct and teucer's is not (even though it got three upvotes despite the fact that the link to Wikipedia provided therein does not support that claim). I am used to seeing random variables with densities of the form $\frac{r}{\sigma^2}\exp(-r^2/2\sigma^2)$ referred to as _Rayleigh_ random variables: they describe the distance from the origin of the point $(X,Y)$ where $X$ and $Y$ are independent $N(0,\sigma^2)$ random variables.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is a square root of [exponential distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) with rate $\pi\lambda$. This means that if $Y\sim\exp(\pi\lambda)$, then $\sqrt{Y}\sim f_X$.

Since your estimate is [maximum likelihood estimate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood) it should be asymptotically normal. This follows immediately from the properties of maximum likelihood estimates. In this particular case:

$$\sqrt{n}(\hat\lambda-\lambda)\to N(0,\lambda^2)$$

since

$$E\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \lambda^2}\log f_X(X)=-\frac{1}{\lambda^2}.$$

Answer (score 11):

Why do you care about asymptotics when the exact answer is just as simple (and exact)?  I am assuming that you want asymptotic normality so that you can use the $\mathrm{Est}\pm z_{\alpha}\mathrm{StdErr}$ type of confidence interval

If you make the probability transformation $Y_{i}=X_{i}^{2}$ then you have an exponential sampling distribution (as @mpiktas has mentioned):

$$\newcommand{\Gamma}{\mathrm{Gamma}}
\newcommand{\MLE}{\mathrm{MLE}}
\newcommand{\Pr}{\mathrm{Pr}}
f_{Y_{i}}(y_{i})=f_{X_{i}}(\sqrt{y_{i}})|\frac{\partial\sqrt{y_{i}}}{\partial y_{i}}|=2 \lambda \pi \sqrt{y_{i}} \exp(-\lambda \pi \sqrt{y_{i}} ^2)\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y_{i}}}=\lambda\pi\exp(-\lambda\pi y_{i})$$

So the joint log-likelihood in terms of $D\equiv\{y_{1},\dots,y_{N}\}$ becomes:

$$\log[f(D|\lambda)]=N\log(\pi)+N\log(\lambda)-\lambda\pi\sum_{i=1}^{N}y_{i}$$

Now the only way the data enters the analysis is through the total $T_{N}=\sum_{i=1}^{N}y_{i}$ (and the sample size $N$).  Now it is an elementary sampling theory calculation to show that $T_{N}\sim \Gamma(N,\pi\lambda)$, and further that $\pi N^{-1}T_{N}\sim \Gamma(N,N\lambda)$.  We can further make this a "pivotal" quantity by taking $\lambda$ out of the equations (via the same way that I just put $N$ into them).  And we have:

$$\lambda\pi N^{-1}T_{N}=\frac{\lambda}{\hat{\lambda}_{\MLE}}\sim \Gamma(N,N)$$

Note that thus we now have a distribution which involves the MLE and whose sampling distribution is independent of the parameter $\lambda$.  Now your MLE is equal to $\frac{1}{\pi N^{-1}T_{N}}$ And so writing quantities $L_{\alpha}$ and $U_{\alpha}$ such that the following holds:

$$\Pr(L_{\alpha} < G < U_{\alpha})=1-\alpha\;\;\;\;\;\;\;G\sim \Gamma(N,N)$$

And we then have:

$$\Pr(L_{\alpha} < \frac{\lambda}{\hat{\lambda}_{\MLE}} < U_{\alpha})=\Pr(L_{\alpha}\hat{\lambda}_{\MLE} > \lambda > U_{\alpha}\hat{\lambda}_{\MLE})=1-\alpha$$

And you have an **exact** $1-\alpha$ confidence interval for $\lambda$.

NOTE: The Gamma distribution I am using is the "precision" style, so that a $\Gamma(N,N)$ density looks like:
$$f_{\Gamma(N,N)}(g)=\frac{N^{N}}{\Gamma(N)}g^{N-1}\exp(-Ng)$$

Comment: Thanks! Really great answer, however I needed to use a normal approximation. I completely understand and agree with your solution though.