# Find confidence interval via pivotal quantity?

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, chi-squared-distribution, pivot

Suppose $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ is a random sample from a population with pdf

$$f(x|\theta) = \dfrac{1}{2\theta}e^{-|x|/\theta},x\in \mathbb{R}$$

The pivotal quantity is $\frac{2}{\theta}\sum_{i=1}^n |X_i|$. How to derive it? How to find pivotal in general?

**Update:**
Is $\frac{2}{\theta}\sum_{i=1}^n |X_i|$ a chi-square distribution?

*P.S.* this problem is from our previous comprehensive exam. We have no answer for it.

Comment: Hint: $X_i / \theta$ is distributed Laplace (another name for this distribution) with scale equal to one.

Comment: Either way I can give some hints: You're trying to estimate $\theta$, which is a scale parameter in the density. Consider, specifically, what happens to $|X|$ when $\theta$ increases or decreases (indeed, consider the distribution of $|X|$ explicitly if that helps). Then consider the definition of a pivotal quantity.

Comment: Could you please show how you arrive at it being chi-square?

Comment: @Glen_b check this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution#Related_distributions)

Comment: $\frac{1}{2} e^{-|x-0|} \sim Laplace(0,1)$, then $\frac{1}{2\theta} e^{-|x-0|/\theta}\sim Laplace(0, 1/\theta)$. According to the link, $\frac{2}{\theta}\sum_{i=1}^n |X_i|\sim \chi (2n)$.

Comment: That's right--because $|X_i|$ is Exponential, sums of iid Exponentials are Gamma, and the $\chi^2$ distribution is a special form of the Gamma. BTW, one way to answer questions about finding pivotal quantities is explained and illustrated (with a closely related distribution) in the answer at http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/10849/919.

Comment: @Jason I already derived it myself when I first saw the question (it's obvious enough if you've done a couple of that sort of question). The point of my question about how you arrived at that result was to try to see whether you were able to make an argument for it being chi-square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An outline of one way to approach it.

Step 1: show that $|X_i|/\theta$~Exponential(1)

Step 2: Hence explain how $\frac{2}{\theta}|X_i|\sim\chi^2_2$

Step 3: Hence give the distribution of $\frac{2}{\theta}\sum_i|X_i|$